# Setting Date Format for multiple date columns in SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have over 65 columns among which there are about 30 Date Columnns. I want to set it to MM/DD/YYYY. Presently it is also showing the time YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. I tried correcting this within the SQL query by using cast. The SQL output shows only date, but it again gets represented in DateTime in SSRS. I dont want to right click on 30 columns manually to set date format. Is there a way to set default date format for all date columns in the report?

Answer (score 1):

"Cast" is not helping here since it is about types, not format.
Try using the "convert" function instead.
In your case, it would be

```
-- use your field name instead of sysdatetime()
select convert(varchar, sysdatetime(), 101/*mm/dd/yyyy format Id*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select all the fields in the tablix and change the formatting together. You may wish to consider using a parameter for the formatting.